# Heterogeneous resources in shift rostering

Tags: optaplanner

In a shift rostering problem, how would you model a situation in which the number of employees needed depends on how good the employees are?

The advice given in the optaplanner documentation and elsewhere is that you should divide a many-to-many relationship into a many-to-one and one-to-many.  In the nurserostering example, this results in a Shift, ShiftAssignment and Employee.

But in nurserostering, Shift has a fixed requiredEmployeeSize property.  In my problem, I can't have a fixed value here.  The number of employees required is determined by the capacity of the employees.

How would you do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was down-voted.  The question points out a fundamental limitation to optaplanner, and a good answer or work-around would apply to many problem domains.

Comment: Sound more like Bin Packing than like Employee Rostering. Does the CloudBalance example (which is a form of Bin Packing) inspire?

Comment: By the way, I love the effort you've put into documentation and polish.  It really helps a lot.  Regarding the CloudBalance problem, my particular problem would be analogous to the CloudBalance problem but with Processes so large they can sometimes fit into more than one Computer (and the number of Computers needed would depend on the size of the Process and capacity of the Computer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, define a numeric `capacity` variable in your `Employee` class and a numeric `need` variable in `Shift` class.

Then, you can use a rule like the following one. For each shift, this rule will apply a penalty if insufficient total capacity is assigned.

```
rule "Insufficient Capacity Assignment"
    when
        $shift : Shift(need > 0, $need : need)
        $totalCapacity : Number() from accumulate(
            $assignment : ShiftAssignment(employee != null, shift == $shift, $capacity : employee.getCapacity() ),
            sum($capacity)
        )
        eval($totalCapacity.intValue() < $need)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, 1, -10);
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the detailed example!

Comment: Your're welcome. You can select it as accepted answer if it helped ;)